# iOS 7 Views reposition under status bar using topLayoutGuide

Tags: layout, ios7, statusbar

I have seen many confusing and heck solutions to deal with status bar in iOS 7 but I liked following solution as mentioned by Apple at - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926

....but it doesn't work! This method gets called as expected but childView is not moving down 20 pixels.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        UIView *childView = self.childController.view;
        id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
        CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length; //I checked this valued is 20
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (childView, topGuide);
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[topGuide]-20-[childView]"
                                                                          options: 0
                                                                          metrics: nil
                                                                            views: viewsDictionary
                                   ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Following works for me but I would really like to solve this problem using AutoLayout using topLayoutGuide.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect frame = self.bounds;
        frame.origin.y = 20;
        frame.size.height -= 20;
        self.childView.frame = frame;
    } else {
        self.childView.frame = self.bounds;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why using topLayoutGuide not working? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to instead place this logic within - (void)updateViewConstraints instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418548/where-to-add-toplayoutguide-constraint-code