# Where to add topLayoutGuide constraint code

Tags: ios, autolayout

### Solution

Figured out a solution, put the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method of my subclassed navigation controller .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f) {
        [[self view] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        id topGuide = [self topLayoutGuide];
        UIView * selfView = [self view];
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (selfView, topGuide);
        [[[self view] window] addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[topGuide]-0-[selfView]"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary]
        ];
        [[[self view] window] layoutSubviews]; // You must call this method here or the system raises an exception
    }
}
```

### Original Post

Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide) didn't say it clear that where (which class, which method) should I put this chunk of code (don't know what does `self` refers to in the code):

```
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
id topGuide = myViewController.topLayoutGuide;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (button, topGuide);
[myViewController.view addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V: [topGuide]-20-[button]"
                                                 options: 0
                                                 metrics: nil
                                                   views: viewsDictionary]
self.view layoutSubviews; // You must call this method here or the system raises an exception
];
```

And I feel that the above chunk of code has some typo, so here's what I think it should be:

```
[button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
id topGuide = myViewController.topLayoutGuide;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings (button, topGuide);
[myViewController.view addConstraints:
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V: [topGuide]-20-[button]"
                                                 options: 0
                                                 metrics: nil
                                                   views: viewsDictionary]
];
self.view.layoutSubviews; // You must call this method here or the system raises an exception
```

Comment: I suggest you to add it as a method to some category on UIButton.
For example `UIButton+CustomLayOut` & then call it. However you can also implement in `appDelegate` class in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, `self` can refer to a view controller. With this code, your are adding constraint to its view, so it can layout it subviews as you set them when calling `layoutSubviews`. If you add this code in the `viewDidLoad` method (and I recommand you to add it there) you can replace occurrences of `myViewController` by `self`

Comment: To @zbMax Then what's the relationship between self and myViewController in the code?

Comment: If you put this code in a view controller to set constraint for its view and subviews, you should replace `myViewController` by `self`

Comment: layoutSubviews should not be called directly, it is for override only. If you need to layout subviews call setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded